# Какие паттерны для подтверждения операций пользователя использовать?

Tags: java, android

Представим себе любую форму ввода данных, в несколько полей.

Какие у нас есть варианты для подтверждения введённых данных?

Прошу поделиться опытом. И дать оценку предложенному варианту.

Какие есть варианты для Android?

Например:

Кнопка `ОК` - `ОТМЕНА`, где-нибудь внизу экрана.
В тулбаре слева сверху крестик - справа галочка ( приложения GMail - Mail.ru) - кстати как думаете прижился ли этот паттерн?
На wear устройствах, это так называемый `ConfirmationActivity`.

Лично мне вариант с тулбаром очень понравился, и хочется его использовать везде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "подтверждения введённых данных"? Выделить красным поля которые не прошли проверку или как?

Comment: Сценарий:  требуется что то ввести, например реквизиты платежа.  Поля ввода (т.к. их много), вынесены на отдельный экран. Мы переходим на этот экран, и после того как ввели все данные, хотим вернуться к предыдущей форме. Типо ОК нажали и вернулись на предыдущий экран. Или какой то другой паттерн.
В скниншоте видно, что в тулбаре есть крестик ( вместо кнопки ОТМЕНА) и иконка бумажного самолета ( вместо ОК). Вот я и хочу понять как лучше сделать. И есть ли еще какие то варианты

Answer (score 1):

Гугл предлагает свои [гайдлайны](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/design/index.html) в зависимости от версии ОС. Для интерфейсов android 2.х, 4.х, 5.х они отличаются - в данный момент это Material Design. Рекомендуется не выдумывать, а придерживаться именно их, как наиболее ожидаемый для пользователя юзкейс.

Это касается не только расположения элементов, но и их внешнего вида, так например, иконка "бумажного самолетика" - отправить сообщение. Подтверждение введенных данных - "косая галочка"